# Do Kryptonians get powers from > 6000k suns?

Tags: dc, superman

Superman's powers come from being near a yellow sun as opposed to the red sun of krypton. Occasionally Superman will travel to other planets/off-world to help some other cause or force.

I'm curious, has any writer had the man of steel utilize the radiation from another different colored (blue, white etc) sun for his powers? Do hotter stars have similar affects, or are Kryptonian powers only activated by yellow suns?

Comment: http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Photonucleic_Effect

Comment: Not a duplicate, but definitely answered my question!